# Assertion Failed when trying to run projectPoints

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I keep getting an `assertion failed`(0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size())`in cv::_InputArray::getMat,` in file `matrix.cpp` when trying to run projectPoints. I have checked everything I can think of but I can't work out what's wrong. My guess is something went wrong with the calibratecamera but I don't know how I would find out what is wrong exactly. Here is my code, thanks.

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
std::vector<cv::Point3f> Generate3DPoints()
{
  std::vector<cv::Point3f> points;

  float x,y,z;

  x=.5;y=.5;z=.5;
  points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x,y,z));

  x=0;y=0;z=0;
  points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x,y,z));

  x=-0;y=0;z=.5;
  points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x,y,z));

  x=0;y=.5;z=.5;
  points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x,y,z));

  x=0;y=-.5;z=0;
  points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x,y,z));

  x=.5;y=0;z=.5;
  points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x,y,z));

  x=.5;y=0;z=0;
  points.push_back(cv::Point3f(x,y,z));

  /*
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
    {
    std::cout << points[i] << std::endl;
    }
  */
  return points;
}
int main()
{
    int numBoards = 4;
    int numCornersHor = 6;
    int numCornersVer = 9;
    int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
    Size board_sz = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);

    VideoCapture capture = VideoCapture(0);

    vector<vector<Point3f>> object_points;
    vector<vector<Point2f>> imagePoints;
    vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;
    vector<Point3f> objectPoints1 = Generate3DPoints();

    vector<Point2f> corners;
    int successes=0;

    Mat image;
    Mat gray_image;
    //capture >> image;
    Sleep(1000);
    capture.read(image);

    imshow("Welcome", image);
    vector<Point3f> obj;
    for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)
    obj.push_back(Point3f(j/numCornersHor, j%numCornersHor, 0.0f));

    while(successes<numBoards)
    {
        cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

        if(found)
        {
            cornerSubPix(gray_image, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners, found);
            cout << "SUCESS\n";

        }
        else
            cout << "FAIL\n";

        imshow("win1", image);
        imshow("win2", gray_image);

        capture.read(image); 
        image_points.push_back(corners);
        object_points.push_back(obj);
        printf("Snap stored!\n");
        char continues;
        cout << "Press c to continue\n";
        cin >> continues;
        successes++;

        //if(successes>=numBoards)
         //   break;


    }

    Mat intrinsic = Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
    Mat distCoeffs;
    vector<Mat> rvecs;
    vector<Mat> tvecs;

    intrinsic.ptr<float>(0)[0] = 1;
    intrinsic.ptr<float>(1)[1] = 1;

    calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

    cout << "Done\n";


    projectPoints(objectPoints1, rvecs, tvecs, intrinsic, distCoeffs, imagePoints);

    cout << "done2";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *which* assertion failed ?

Comment: Sorry [here is a snip](http://i.imgur.com/zhH7JBt.png) of it.

Comment: add it as text to the question

Comment: it looks like an index out of range. Try run it with a debugger

Comment: Get the same thing using a debugger.

Comment: `0 (= i` ?? `i ( (int)vv.size()`??

Comment: @zoska, typo, see edit above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to pass `rvecs` and `tvecs` to the function `projectPoints`, which expects `Mat` and not `vector<Mat>`.

Basically, the `calibrateCamera` function estimates the intrinsics matrix and distortion coefficients of the camera using several images of a chessboard. The function also returns multiple versions of the extrinsics parameters (rotation+translation), one for each image you used. These extrinsic parameters are stored in `rvecs` and `tvecs`.

However, you want to project the 3D points in only one of these images, so you should choose what set of extrinsic parameters you want (i.e. `rvecs[i]` and `tvecs[i]`, `i` corresponding to the image in which you want to project your object) and call `projectPoints` for these extrinsic parameters only, not the whole `vectors<Mat>`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense although the error is still there after I changed the code to...
`calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

 Mat rvecs1 = rvecs[1];
 Mat tvecs1 = tvecs[1];

 projectPoints(objectPoints1, rvecs1, tvecs1, intrinsic, distCoeffs, imagePoints);`

Comment: Thanks for your help I got it, it was a combination of what you said and also my imagePoints was declared wrong. Not sure why to be honest but I changed it to
 `std::vector<cv::Point2f>imagePoints;` And it works now.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me fix a similar bug with solveP2P(). I was porting similar input parameters from the calibrateCamera() function and didn't catch the change.

Comment: This was very useful! for some reason my code still gives me the same error, even though i've tried to do exactly what OneTwo changed in their code